# Retrieving management hierarchy report from db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to prepare report that returns for each of our employee complete list of their higher ups.

I have two mariadb tables: employee and position

employee:
id, name, first_boss_id, position_id,

position:
id, position_name

Employee table contains all employees from juniors to top managers, but every entry contains only name of employee and his closest boss in hierarchy.  How can I get all of the managers above him? I've got this so far:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, p.position_name, b.name, 
FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN employee b ON e.firts_boss_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN position p ON e.position_id = p.id
```

It returns id, name of employee, his carrier position and name of his closest manager/boss. How can I get names of the rest of higher management for this employee? Is it better to use SQL query or write some PHP script to create that report from data I get from query above?

Either way I could really use some pointers how to get it done. Thank you!

Comment: In the future you should consider Closure tables for hierarchies. Take a look at [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) by Bill Karwin starting around slide 40.

Comment: For your current problem you're going to need to use some PHP to run a query recursively until you finally return the person at the top of the hierarchy.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you. Interesting read thanks for link, unfortunetaly the database is part of software created by external firm so I can't do much about it...